# API for document format conversion

Tags: web-services, pdf-generation, documentviewer, document-conversion, format-conversion

I am looking for a RESTful web service to which I can send a document (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx, and tiff at a minimum) for conversion to pdf and swf.

The reason I need swf in addition to pfd is so that I can display the document in the browser using a flash-based document viewer such as [FlexPaper](http://www.flexpaper.devaldi.com/).

I basically want [transloadit.com](http://transloadit.com/) for documents.

One option is to use the Scribd API, download the pdf, and use [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/download.html) to convert the pdf to swf. However I am interested in alternatives.

Comment: Such a web service would be worth a bit of $$$. I'm not aware of any that do what your saying, but to build one yourself would be quite an endeavor (if you didn't want to pay for a fancy API to do the conversions for you).

Comment: It certainly would be an endeavour - this is why I am looking for an existing service. I am currently using Scribd but would like a platform that offers a little more flexibility/specifically targets developers.

Answer (score 2):

doxument.com might be what you looking for. They do offer some kind of REST API. I'm not sure about the formats though.

Comment: Almost what I need. Doesn't appear to support docx or xlsx (http://code.google.com/p/doxument/wiki/Documentation?tm=6#Formats). Also doesn't export to swf. Upvoted though, as good/relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing on http://webservices.io which is in beta and offers document conversion via a REST API.

While it  also doesn't do all the conversions you are asking for, it **does** have docx and xlsx support. See [matrix with supported conversions](https://webservices.io/api/document/converter#supportedConversions)

Comment: You may be able to add another check to that matrix pretty cheaply using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). GPL, it's worked satisfactorily in a few personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose library is best of the best http://www.aspose.com/ Use it for create your own service

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question, however just want to share another solution for future reference.
[GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud REST API](https://products.groupdocs.cloud/conversion) is another option to convert back and forth between over 65+ types of documents and images, including all Microsoft Office and OpenDocument file formats, PDF documents, HTML, CAD, raster images and much more.

cURL sample Code:

```
### Retrieve access token
### TODO: Get your AppSID and AppKey at https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud (free registration is required).
curl --request POST https://api.groupdocs.cloud/connect/token 
--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
--data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[APP_SID]&client_secret=[APP_KEY]"

### Convert and Add Watermark
curl --request POST "https://api.groupdocs.cloud/v2.0/conversion" 
--header "authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]" 
--header "accept: application/json" 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{ "FilePath": "test_doc.docx", "Format": "pdf", "ConvertOptions": { "FromPage": 1, "PagesCount": 1, "WatermarkOptions": { "text": "Watermark" } }, "OutputPath": "Output"}"
```

I work with Aspose as developer evangelist.